# Dropzone.js DIV - not uploading files

Tags: javascript, upload, dropzone.js

I am trying to use dropzone.js (with Coldfusion 9) to upload potentially multiple files on one page. I first did this using the form tag:

```
<cfform name='UploadFiles' action="uploadfiles.cfm" class="dropzone">
```

and this worked as expected. 
The problem is that I need the user to upload the files and then hit a submit button that processes the files. So I would need the information from each of the files uploaded. With this method, since each one is a separate form, I could not get all the file names on submit. Because of this, I changed the tag to a div tag inside of the form:

```
<cfform name='uploadfiles' action="uploadfiles.cfm">
.
.
.
 <div id="my-dropzone" action="uploadfiles.cfm" class="dropzone">
</cfform>
<script>
  new Dropzone(
    url: "/uploadfiles.cfm" // Set the url
  });
</script>
```

This works, as it shows the different dropzones and I can drag and drop a file or select one, but nothing ever gets uploaded to the location. 
I am using the same code I used when the dropzone was a from to upload when the dropzone is a div:

```
  <cffile action="upload" destination="#uploads#\Uploaded\#filen#" nameconflict="makeunique">
```

What am I missing in order for it to actually upload the file?

Comment: Have you checked for syntax errors ?
The code above seems to be missing a "{" right after Dropzone(